# Tensorflow define lossfunction

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function

The following code works, converges and the neural net approximates the exponential on the interval from 0 to 1:

```
#   code works
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#   fit an exponential
n = 101
x = np.linspace(start=0, stop=1, num=n)
y_e = np.exp(x)
#   any odd neural net with sufficient degrees of freedom
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1]),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=50, activation="softmax"),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])
#   loss function
def loss(y_true, y_pred): 
    L_ode = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
    return L_ode
model.compile('adam', loss)
model.fit(x, y_e, epochs=100, batch_size=1)
y_NN = model.predict(x).flatten()
plt.plot(x, y_NN, color='blue')
plt.plot(x, y_e, color='red')
plt.title('NN (blue) and exp (red)')
```

Now I redefine the loss function and replace `y_true` by `tf.zeros(n)` in the `model.fit`. But this code - which should do the same thing - runs nicely but converges to a constant:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#   fit an exponential
n = 101
x = np.linspace(start=0, stop=1, num=n)
y_e = np.exp(x)
#   any odd neural net with sufficient degrees of freedom
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1]),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=50, activation="softmax"),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])
#   loss function
def loss(y_true, y_pred): 
    L_ode = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square((y_pred - y_e) - y_true), axis=-1)
    return L_ode
model.compile('adam', loss)
model.fit(x, tf.zeros(n), epochs=100, batch_size=1)
y_NN = model.predict(x).flatten()
plt.plot(x, y_NN, color='blue')
plt.plot(x, y_e, color='red')
plt.title('NN (blue) and exp (red)')
```

Where is the mistake?

**Background:** I would like to approximate solutions of odes with neural nets and therefore define my own loss-function. The above is a very reduced example of the "zero degree ode" y(x) = exp(x).

Comment: I don't get it. If you're training your model to always try and output `0` regradless of the input, then why are you surprised that it converges to a constant value?

Comment: The loss-function is modified from `tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)` to `tf.reduce_mean(tf.square((y_pred - y_e) - y_true), axis=-1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed above, the issue is with the sampling of batches, the loss function sees random samples from the `x` that you provide to the `fit` function, so you cannot have a `y` value in the loss that is a global variable, because you do not know which value that should be.

But luckily `y_true` in the loss function can be multidimensional, see [the keras docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compile):

> `y_true` should have shape `(batch_size, d0, .. dN)`

so we can just pack multiple values in the inner dimensions. In you case we just need the shape `n,2` to pack your `y_e` (the exponential values) and `y_true` (your `np.zeros`) in there:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#   fit an exponential
n = 101
x = np.linspace(start=0, stop=1, num=n)
y_e = np.exp(x)
y_true = np.zeros(n)

# Pack y_e and y_e in a matrix
y_gt = np.empty((n,2))
y_gt[:,0] = y_e
y_gt[:,1] = y_true


#   any odd neural net with sufficient degrees of freedom
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1]),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=50, activation="softmax"),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])
#   loss function
def loss(y_gt, y_pred):
    y_true = y_gt[:,1]
    y_e = y_gt[:,0]
    L_ode = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square((y_pred - y_e) - y_true), axis=-1)
    return L_ode
model.compile('adam', loss)
model.fit(x, y_gt, epochs=100, batch_size=1)
y_NN = model.predict(x).flatten()
plt.plot(x, y_NN, color='blue')
plt.plot(x, y_e, color='red')
plt.title('NN (blue) and exp (red)')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort, that is the solution. Now I can keep going with my odes.

Comment: please accept the answer then by clicking the mark next to it

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem may be that you are using a global variable (y_e) in the second version of your loss function. There's no guarantee, or even reasonable expectation, that the value of this will be updated in the right way, batch by batch, when the loss function is called.

Loss has to be calculated from y_true and y_pred (plus you can use values that do not change during the course of the training)

Comment: This! Batchsize is 1, so a single output value is compared to ALL 101 points and a mean is taken.

Comment: yes, I can see it. But how can I fix it?

Comment: ... I confess I don't understand why it still doesn't work if we set batch_size=n. So it may possibly not be a complete answer as yet

Comment: @MarcelSteiner-Curtis what prevents you from calculating your loss from y_true and y_pred alone in the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I am not OP. Take care who you ping

Comment: @DavidHarris it is probably sampling from `x` and `y_true`, hence there is probably no guarantee that the order is the same

Comment: @DavidHarris: Thanks for your thoughts! I need y_e to be able to solve eg. y'+y=y_e which can be solved by minimising `tf.reduce_mean(tf.square((DIFF(y_pred,x) + y_pred - y_e) - y_true), axis=-1)` where `DIFF' needs to be defined further.

Comment: @FlyingTeller ops... sorry :-)